# Flow To Update Account Owner from Closed Won Opportunity Owner

Tags: visual-workflow, field-update, automation

I am trying to build a Flow to automatically update the Account Owner to be the same as the Opportunity Owner when an Opportunity of a certain Record Type "Paywall Assist" is Closed Won.

This is easy for me to do in in Process Builder, but I'd like to build it in a Flow since Process Builder is going away.

I've started by building a record triggered flow to trigger the flow when a record is created or updated and to meet the proper entry conditions:
[image]

I then added an Update Records element based on the criteria below. The goal is to update the Account Owner to be the same as the Opportunity Owner of the Closed Won Opportunity.

[image]

However, when I debug the flow, I get the error below. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query currently says

> Find **all Account** records where OwnerId Does not equal {!$Record.OwnerId}

That will update all accounts in your org that don't have that Owner which, as your error suggests, can be more than 10,000 records.

What you want is to make sure you're filtering for **Accounts related to the Opportunity that met criteria for your record-triggered flow**.

Flow provides this through the [$Record global variable](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_resources_global_variables.htm&type=5)

> In a record-triggered flow, the $Record global variable contains the triggering record’s values. You can reference and change $Record values throughout the flow.

In this case, it's as simple as using the record variable provided to you in the flow. You'll want to add a criteria to see that

`Account's Id = Record(Opportunity)'s Account Id.`

[image]

Comment: Gonclaves - Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! It worked. I sincerely appreciate your help